# Remain in "SQL Mode" in Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Right now, if I want to enter SQL queries in Microsoft Access, I do this:

Click the Create tab, then Query design button, then close the popup. Click the SQL button. Type my query. Click Run.

For my next query, I have to do that all over again. How can I stay in an SQL environment in Access?

Answer (score 3):

Newer versions of Access still support many of the same keyboard shortcuts for the old Menu commands (in addition to the newer, longer keyboard shortcuts for the Ribbon interface). So, in the Access 2010 query designer I still use:

<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>, <kbd>d</kbd> which was **V**iew > **D**esign View
<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>, <kbd>s</kbd> which was **V**iew > Data**S**heet View
<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>, <kbd>q</kbd> which was **V**iew > S**Q**L View

To run an action query, this old keyboard shortcut still works, too:

<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>, <kbd>r</kbd> which was **Q**uery > **R**un

Answer (score 0):

Ah, it turns out it's one of the view modes (first button in the Home tab). Because none of my functions required a table, I hadn't bothered to choose a table to work in, which means the View menu was grayed out.